# How can you use Azure API Management policy to load balance calls to a backend service?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

How can you use policy to load balance calls to a pair of backend services? *(in this case a pair of Logic Apps in different regions)*

I've read through the [API Management policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policies) and can see something around the [control flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#choose) but I can't work out how to (a) test the back-end service is available, and then (b) change the call to the backup service if the primary is unavailable

```
<backend>  
     <forward-request/>  
</backend>
```

Answer (score 2):

One more way to achieve this could be that you can use the [retry policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#a-nameretrya-retry) with [set backend service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBackendService) or [send-request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#a-namesendrequesta-send-request)

with something like

```
<backend>
    <retry condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 400 || context.Response.StatusCode >= 500)" count="10" interval="10" max-interval="100" delta="10" first-fast-retry="false">
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Response != null && (context.Response.StatusCode == 400 || context.Response.StatusCode >= 500)">
                <set-backend-service base-url="http://echoapibackup.cloudapp.net/api" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <set-backend-service base-url="http://echoapi.cloudapp.net/api" />
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
        <forward-request />
    </retry>
</backend>
```

This will in case your primary backend returns an error, will keep retrying on your backup backend.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using send-request policy. With it (and wait policy) you could make parallel calls to a couple of web services and return result from one that completes first. That would mean that you need to skip forward-request altogether as you'll be getting result data from these policies.

Or you could use send-request to test if certain backend is available and then use set-backend-service and/or rewrite-uri policies to change destination backend. In that case you'll be keeping forward-request.