# Can Azure APIM route the region specific requests to our nearby ApiServers

Tags: azure, autoscaling, azure-api-management

I have several Azure APIM instances running across different-different geographical region. And it routes all the requests our specific API's hosted on ApiServers. Now I have planned to have multiple Instances of APIServers, across different-different regions.

My Question is:

1. Can APIM do healthcheck and detect if APIServer is running or not? CAn it dynamically detect that a new APIServer instance is up in a new geo-region now?
2. Can APIM route the region specific requests to our nearby ApiServers? Realtime Scaling
3. Can I configure APIM to route all Get request to a single region specific ApiServers ?

Comment: You can do this using policies. Please refer o https://stackoverflow.com/a/43510482/5906211

Comment: Yes, the third point I can achieve through policies. And I believe the 2nd point should be taken by AZURE itself automatically. Since my backend service is also on Azure only.

Comment: Disclaimer: Nothing happens automatically. If you want load balancing you will have to design for it. Put your ApiServers behind a load balancer, or use  the `retry-policy` to choose a backend using `set-backend` policy, when a failure happens